# how to input multiple variables through single scanf

Tags: c

The question

> A maths teacher asks her students to give 3 examples for positive odd numbers. When the student specifies a correct answer, his/her score is incremented by 1. When the student specifies a positive even number, his/her score is decremented by 0.5. When the student specifies a negative number, he/she will not be given any more chances to correct his or her mistake and his/her score will be decremented by 1. So a student's turn comes to an end when he/she has correctly specified 3 positive odd numbers or when the student has specified a negative number.
>
> Few students didn't know the difference between odd numbers and even numbers and they made many mistakes and so it was difficult for the teacher to maintain the scores. The teacher asks for your help.
>
> Can you please help her by writing a  program to calculate the score?

Sample Input 1:
1
3
5
Sample Output 1:
3.0

Sample Input 2:
1
2
5
6
7
Sample Output 2:
2.0

Sample Input 3:
2
-4
Sample Output 3:
-1.5

Sample Input 4:
3
3
3
Sample Output 4:
3.0

---

**Problem:**

here i am not getting how to input multiple variables through single scanf

---

here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int a,i;
    float b=0;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        do
        {
            if(a%2==0)
            {
                b=b-0.5;
            }
            if(a<0)
            {
                b--;
            }
            else if(a%2!=0)
            {
                b++;
            }
            printf("%.1f",b);
        }
        while(a%2!=0);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Formatting is very important to make code readable, especially indentation. Also, what's wrong with your code? Doesn't it build? Doesn't it work as expected? Does it crash? Does it present unexpected output? Something else?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I dug out the problem and turned it into a meaningful title.

Comment: Do you know how to print multiple values with `printf`? The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) family of functions functions very similar. Not that there's anything wrong by getting one input at a time in a loop.

Comment: DO NOT USE a, b, c, d ....upto... z AS VARIABLE.  You will soon _out of stock_ after declaring 26 variables! Use meaningful variable instead.

Comment: According to you samples student can input as many numbers he wants  in a single go  3 numbers or 5 numbers or even 1 number  or whatever he wants .

Comment: i have to input digits until it gets 3 odd numbers or a negative digit, that;s why i gave the sample input , output for an idea... i don't get it how to do it

Comment: @rakeb.void thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, the following `for` loop will just iterate only `3` times:

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
```

whereas you input can be more than `3` times (see Sample Input 2)!

There are some syntactical issues besides some logical error in your code.

- Instead of `float b=0;` use `float b = 0.0;`

Note that, if the input is negative even number then the following code will reduce `b` by `0.5`

```
if(a%2==0)
{
   b=b-0.5;
}
```

Where the immediate `if` condition will again reduce `b` by `1`.

```
if(a<0)
{
   b--;
}
```

that will make your result more reduced by `0.5`, which is not correct.

As per your problem definition, the *Sample Input* is variable so that you have to implement your loop as well. Try something like this:

```
int input, correctResultCount = 0;
float result = 0.0;
while (true) {
    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (input < 0) {
        result--;
        break;
    }
    if (input % 2 == 0) {
        result = result - 0.5;
    }
    if (input % 2 != 0) {
        result++;
        correctResultCount++;
    }
    if (correctResultCount == 3)
        break;
}
printf("%.1f", result);
```

[Run Live.](http://ideone.com/jGzNU3)

Answer (score 0):

```
                                 **NOTE**
```

THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT 
          **"A Student's turn comes to an end when he/she has correctly specified 3 positive odd numbers or when the student has specified a negative number"**

i.e  HE CAN GIVE ANY NUMBER OF EVEN NUMBERS (2,4,6,8,10...) BUT THIS WILL HALT ONLY WHEN A TOTAL OF 3 ODD NUMBERS ARE GIVEN OR A SINGLE NEGATIVE NUMBER.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num;
    float marks=0.0 ;
    for(int i=0;i<3;)
        {
          cin>>num;
          if(num<0)
            {
               marks=marks-1;
               break;
            }
          else if(num%2==0)
            {

                marks=marks-0.5;    

            }
        else{
                marks=marks+1;
                i++;
            }
        }

  cout<<"Final MArks Are :"<<marks<<endl;

}
```

SAMPLE INPUT & OUTPUT 1:

1 3 5 ->3.0

SAMPLE INPUT & OUTPUT 2:

1 2 5 6 7 -> 2.0